# Different justification in cells

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

The following code will center the text in all cells.

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \small
    \caption{my caption}
    \label{my label}
    \begin{tabular}{| C{5cm} | C{2cm} |}
        \hline
        Name           &     Age   \\
        \hline
        First person   &  20  \\
        \hline 
        Second person  &  25  \\      
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

So the output is

```
 +-------------------+---------+
 |        Name       |   Age   |
 +-------------------+---------+
 |    First person   |    20   |
 +-------------------+---------+
 |   Second person   |    25   |
 +-------------------+---------+
```

However I want to center the first row only. Other rows should be left justified

```
 +-------------------+---------+
 |        Name       |   Age   |
 +-------------------+---------+
 | First person      | 20      |
 +-------------------+---------+
 | Second person     | 25      |
 +-------------------+---------+
```

What is the correct code?

Comment: Use `p{5cm} | p{2cm}` for your `tabular` column specification instead, and add `\centering` to each of the headings (`Name` and `Age`). You should also consider using the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)... because it's awesome...

Comment: How is the `C` column type defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column specification holds for all rows in a specific column, unless modified otherwise. So, pick your column specification to match what the majority of your column content would require, and manually adjust the others:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering\small
  \caption{my caption}\label{tbl:label1}
  \begin{tabular}{| p{5cm} | p{2cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Age} \\
    \hline
    First person   &  20  \\
    \hline
    Second person  &  25  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering\small
  \caption{my caption}\label{tbl:label2}
  \begin{tabular}{ p{5cm} p{2cm} }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Age} \\
    \midrule
    First person   &  20  \\
    Second person  &  25  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Since [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)' motto is to avoid vertical rules *at all costs*, adjustments in terms of horizontal alignment is not that easily visible, perhaps even weird (using your example).

Comment: Not using multicolumn, when I add `\centering Age \\ ` in the last column (right most column), the whole table will mess-up

Comment: @mahmood: Yes, then you need to add `\usepackage{array}` to your document preamble and use `\centering\arraybackslash` (you only need this for the last entry in the row).